# PHP Strip Zeros From String of Numbers

Tags: php, string, laravel, formatting, format

Currently, I have a SKU that is a string that is LS181004. I want to convert that string to just 18104. However, I am having problems with strings that have a 1010 in it as it gets reduced to 11 and I need the 10's to stay in the string. Problems are strings like LS121010, LS101010 etc.

For example,
LS101010 should be returned as LS101010.
LS101002 should be returned as LS10102.
LS121010 should be returned as LS121010.
LS120804 should be returned as LS1284.

Code:

```
public function format()
{


    $count =0;
    $sku = str_replace("LS", "", $this->SKU, $count);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $sku = str_replace("01", "1", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("02", "2", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("03", "3", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("04", "4", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("05", "5", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("06", "6", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("07", "7", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("08", "8", $sku);
        $sku = str_replace("09", "9", $sku);

        $this->SKU = $sku;
        $this->save();
    }


    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly on what basis/rules a given string should be transformed into your desired resulting string. This is not clear enough at the moment.

Comment: And for the case LS181104 should it become LS18114 or remain as is? You need to expose more details about the rule

Comment: LS181104 should be returned as 18114. LS101010 should be returned as 101010. LS120810 should be returned as LS12810.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
$sku = str_replace("LS", "", $this->SKU, $count);
        if ($count > 0) {
            $ls = strpos($this->SKU, 'LS');

            $num1 = substr($this->SKU, $ls+2, 2);
            $num2 = substr($this->SKU, $ls+4, 2);
            $num3 = substr($this->SKU, $ls+6, 2);

            if ((int) $num1 < 10) {
                $num1 = str_replace("01", "1", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("02", "2", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("03", "3", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("04", "4", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("05", "5", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("06", "6", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("07", "7", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("08", "8", $num1);
                $num1 = str_replace("09", "9", $num1);

                //replace original num1 with new single digit num1 in $sku
                $sku = str_replace(substr($this->SKU, $ls+2, 2), $num1, $sku);
            }

            if ((int) $num2 < 10 && ($num1 != $num2)) {
                $num2 = str_replace("01", "1", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("02", "2", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("03", "3", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("04", "4", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("05", "5", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("06", "6", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("07", "7", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("08", "8", $num2);
                $num2 = str_replace("09", "9", $num2);

                $sku = str_replace(substr($this->SKU, $ls+4, 2), $num2, $sku);
            }

            if ((int) $num3 < 10 && ($num2 != $num3) && ($num1 != $num3)) {
                $num3 = str_replace("01", "1", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("02", "2", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("03", "3", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("04", "4", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("05", "5", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("06", "6", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("07", "7", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("08", "8", $num3);
                $num3 = str_replace("09", "9", $num3);

                $sku = str_replace(substr($this->SKU, $ls+6, 2), $num3, $sku);
            }

            $this->SKU = $sku;
            $this->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, what you need to do is to split the number in 4 parts, i.e.

"LS" and three 2-digit numbers.

To get the numbers you just use **substr** php function

```
$num1 = substr($this->SKU, 2, 2); // get char 3 and 4
$num1 = substr($this->SKU, 4, 2); // 5 and 6
$num1 = substr($this->SKU, 6, 2); // 7 and 8
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

then if each of the three numbers is less than 10 you remove the zero in the front

```
$num1 = (int)$num1; // casting to integer will do, no conditional needed
$num2 = (int)$num2;
$num3 = (int)$num3;

$sku = 'LS' . $num1 . $num2 . $num3; // concatenate back, and that's it
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks this was a great start. There were a couple edge cases where this didnt work. For example, LS040404X needs to have the X on the end. I think I found the solution with your help.